# Mongodb extract documents if the time of element A is less than the time of element B in the same document

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection

```
 db.Tratte.insert(
    {
    "TransportID":["9901","9903"],
    "StopsBy":[
     {"Station":"Roma Termini",
     "StopsAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T09:05:00Z"),
     "LeavesAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T09:25:00Z")},
      {"Station":"Napoli Centrale",
     "StopsAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T10:37:00Z"),
     "LeavesAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T10:52:00Z")},
     {"Station":"Salerno",
     "StopsAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T11:35:00Z")}]
    })

 db.Tratte.insert(
        {
        "TransportID":"9999",
        "StopsBy":[
         {"Station":"Salerno",
         "StopsAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T09:05:00Z"),
         "LeavesAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T09:25:00Z")},
          {"Station":"Napoli Centrale",
         "StopsAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T10:37:00Z"),
         "LeavesAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T10:52:00Z")},
         {"Station":"Roma Termini",
         "StopsAt":ISODate("2016-01-01T11:35:00Z")}]
        })
```

and given in input two stations, I want only those documents in which the time of station A is less than the time of the station B. For example, if I choose as station A Roma Termini and as station B Salerno, the system must return the first document above (because time(Roma)time(Salerno))

I'm thinking that the only way to do this is to extract all the documents which contain both the stations, retrieve their time and if they match my criteria return the document. But this solution it's too artifact. Is there a single query to do this?

My final goal is this:
I need a way to get, for example, Roma --> Salerno documents but not Salerno --> Roma documents when users search for two stations. The problem is that I get both directions but I want only the right one.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb is not designed for this kind of querying, It might be worth looking at relational database for storing relational data.

You could however re-model your document for your given usage?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the `$gt` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gt), which matches all the documents with a special field greater than a value. Use it when you [query](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/) your documents.

Comment: My problem is that I'm not able to retrieve with one single query the documents with the stations given in input and the criteria that time of station A < time of station B. Doing the queries separately maybe works but I think it's not the best way